# get product id from quote id - Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, cart, quote

Hi need toget the product id of in a quote item.i have the qoute id with me and tried the below code but product id does not seem to display from the quote.

```
$quoteId=784;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $quoteId)
->getFirstItem();
echo $pid = $quote[product_id] ;
```

Please help to get product id from quote id .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the quote ID already, you might be better just loading a quote object.

`$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);`

Once you've loaded the quote object, you need to get the items from the quote - these are stored separately, as a quote can have many items.

`$quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();`

I don't know if you're only interested in the "first" item or not, but you should be able to change the below:

```
foreach($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
    $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
    // do something with the product, i.e. $product->getId();
}
```